# Forest-based classification and regression error 110180 using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, regression

I tried to train a model to predict a binary output, while I used 12 bands from Sentinel-2 satellite images as the explanatory training raster, but there's an error showed that there was not enough variability in the fields.

However, when I tried to use the same data in a previous project that had ran successfully, there's no such a problem.

I'm wondering where the problem is, as I need to train other models by using these 12 bands, and I think it's not a problem from these 12 bands.

Comment: Have you done a spectral separability analysis (eg., Bhattacharryya or Jeffries-Matusita distance)? This is fairly standard practice in exploratory analysis before specifying a model. This would tell you definitively it there is no variation in your design matrix. Honestly, you could do this in a spread sheet so, not really software limited.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I don't think there is any problem about the spectral separability analysis. Actually, I firstly used several vegetation index as 'Explanatory training raster', and it ran successfully, but when I tried to use the bands from satellite images in another project, it failed. However, when I change the explanatory training raster in the first model from vegetation index into the bands, it can also run successfully. So it is quite wired, and I can't see what spectral separability analysis can help in this case.